# Crystal Report does not display toolbar correctly

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am using Crystal Report version 13.0.2 for Visual Studio 2010. when display the report it does not show the toolbar properly. is there any solution to fix it? Please help!!!!
[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to follow these steps

1) `<div mce_keep="true">`Copy and paste the aspnet_client and all subfolders and files contained within into the C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ directory.

2) `<div mce_keep="true">`Open IIS, select your website, right click and select create new virtual directory. Call this directory `aspnet_client` and point it to the aspnet_client folder you have created in step 1.`</div>`

3) `<div mce_keep="true">` Right click the virtual directory you have just created and select permissions. Add read permission for the IIS WPG account (I am using Windows SBS 2003 with IIS 6 this account may differ if you have a different OS).`</div>`

refer this [link](https://shaunakpandit.wordpress.com/2008/09/10/crystal-report-toolbar-images-not-displayed-aspnet/) may help you

Comment: thanks for review! i try this but it is not working. In localhost it show the error: "NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:49338/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/drill_cursor.cur" what is this?